# Pandas add a new column identifier when reading multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading 40 CSV's with monthly data. The files share the same column structure but are of different length. Crucially, the data doesn't contain any identifiers for the individual months.

How could you add a new 'month' column to the concatenated DataFrame in which the rows for month 1 have a 1, the row for month 2 have a 2, etc. I'm almost there with this but after numerous iterations I just can't get it to work.

```
import glob
path = r'/Users/Name/Downloads/'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
month = 0

for file_ in allFiles:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_, parse_dates=True)
    list_.append(data)
    data['month'] = month += 1 # This is the line I can't get right
firstData = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: do this data['month'+str(month)] = month + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement to the answer of Mathias711. As I understand, you don't need a separate column for each month. So you should insert your `i` into the same `month` column:

```
for i, file_ in enumerate(allFiles):
    data = pd.read_excel(file_, parse_dates=True)
    data['month'] = i    # here is the change
    list_.append(data)
```

So, one `month` column in the concatenated DataFrame will contain index of source file for each row.

Looking at your code I see syntax error: you try to increment your counter on the same line as assigning it to the column values. Also you add `month` column *after* you've already appended the `data` to the `list_`. Something like this should work:

```
month = 0
for file_ in allFiles:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_, parse_dates=True)
    data['month'] = month
    month += 1
    list_.append(data)
```

However, the decision with `enumerate` is more elegant and pythonic. :)

Answer (score 1):

With an `enumerate` you have the identifier you need, just rename the column with this identifier in it:

```
for i, file_ in enumerate(allFiles):
    data = pd.read_excel(file_, parse_dates=True)
    data.rename(columns={'month': 'month_{}'.format(i)})
    list_.append(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get something like

```
month1, month2  
1     , 2
1     , 2
```

You can do this :

```
data['month'+str(month)] = month + 1
list_.append(data)
```

if you want to get something like this for the first iteration

```
month 
1     
1
```

for the second iteration

```
month 
2     
2
```

You can do this :

```
data['month'] = month + 1
list_.append(data)
```

Notice that the `list_.append(..)` has to occur after you add month to the dataframe.